# How to access Blackberry native calendar to save timezone

Tags: blackberry, java-me, calendar

I want to develop a blackberry app which saves the timezone in the native calendar and gets the events for that timezone.

Is this possible?  Are there any APIs exposed to save the timezone? How do I get the events for a timezone?